# Vue 2 load ajax data before component render

Tags: javascript, ajax, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a few nested Vue Components and the child loads the data using an AJAX call. Is it possible to have the parent wait to finish mounting until the child has made the ajax call and finished rendering? I have seen some solutions that use async created() or beforeRouteEnter: function (to, from, next) but I cannot seem to get it to work on the Fiddle.

I have a jsfiddle posted here: https://jsfiddle.net/likwidmonster/20potzwc/16/

In the jsfiddle, I have nextTick functions that print to the log when each is loaded. I would like it to have the following output:

```
grandchild next tick
child next tick
grandchild next tick
child next tick
grandchild next tick
child next tick
parent next tick
```

Comment: Would [`v-cloak`](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-cloak) fit your use case?

Comment: @zero298 I am not sure how I would use v-cloak in the scenario.

Comment: Given your setup, the child will have to communicate with the parent when the loading has completed to allow the parent to display. @zero298's suggestion of using `v-cloak` is to keep the element hidden until you're ready. However, that "readiness" is under your explicit control in this scenario. I do not believe a standard `nextTick` will work for you here.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I am a bit new to Vue JS and am not sure how to communicate to the parent when the child has finished loading and then causing the parent to load. Would I emit from the child to alert the parent it has finished? I don't know how to hold the parent from loading until it receives that message.

Comment: Gave you an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot stop the parent from `loading` so to speak, but you can make it seem like it is by applying `v-cloak`, `v-if`, or `v-show` to the top level HTML element in the template. You can have a property on the parent, such as:

```
loaded: false
```

You can then use `sync` to synchronize this value with the parent and child, by attaching it to the child like this:

```
<child :loaded.sync="loaded"></child>
```

Then, within the child, you can use `$emit` when your `Promise` resolves:

```
this.$emit('update:loaded', true)
```

Which will tell the parent to change `loaded` from `false` to `true`.

Finally, you can make sure the parent isn't rendering until that variable is try by attaching a `v-show` directive which and passing it the `loaded` variable:

```
<div v-show="loaded">
```

So on initial page load this is `false`. When the data is finished loading and the child `$emit`'s, then it will be `true`, and the parent will become visible.

Comment: Since the parent has multiple children won't the parent think the all of the children have loaded prematurely since loaded will be set to true after the first child has loaded? I appreciate your help with this!

Comment: @likwidmonster That's very true and an oversight on my part - do you happen to use Vuex?

Comment: I am not using Vuex yet.

Comment: @likwidmonster Off the top of my head the easiest way I could think of to do this is to register each child in the vuex store on `created()` and give them a status of `false`. Then after each ajax request fires, update the store for said child component and set the status to `true`. Finally, return a `getter` from the store that loops all of the children and returns `true` if they're all loaded or `false` if even one if them isn't. Then in the parent, use a `computed property` bound to the `getter` to  return that value and use it in the `v-show`